# Cannot access this.props from string to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to know why i can use `this.props` directly but i can't use `this.props` from string into `function`.

the error is:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')

here a sample code i've tried:

```
state={
  stringToFn="this.props.navigation.navigate(\'otherscreen\')",
  stringToFn2="alert(\'otherscreen\')"
}

renderThis(){
  let nyobaFunc = new Function("return " + "()=>{"+this.state.stringToFn+"}")();
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={nyobaFunc} style={styles.flatListButton}>
      <CustomText style={styles.flatListSubTitle}>{'HitMe!'}</CustomText>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

render(){
  return(
    {this.renderThis()}
  )
}
```

but if i put `stringToFn` value into `onPress` directly or if i change `this.state.stringToFn` to `this.state.stringToFn2` in `nyobaFunc`, it's work like a charm

can anyone help me why this can be happened?

Comment: You are using safari ? Only safari shows errors in this style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to bind this to your function:

```
state={
  stringToFn="this.props.navigation.navigate(\'otherscreen\')",
  stringToFn2="alert(\'otherscreen\')"
}

renderThis(){
  let nyobaFunc = new Function(`return ${this.state.stringToFn}`);
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={nyobaFunc.bind(this)} style={styles.flatListButton}>
      <CustomText style={styles.flatListSubTitle}>{'HitMe!'}</CustomText>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

render(){
  return(
    {this.renderThis()}
  )
}
```

This is not a good practice - each renders the bind will create a new function - instead of using `new Function` I recommended that you move this functionallity into normal function with parameter.

Comment: still show the same error, i know this method is not good to implementing, but i'm not used it for complex screen, so i think i can handle it

Comment: inside renderThis method the this.props.navigation is exists? @fiix

Comment: i used `react navigation` and i've defined my component in routes, so yes `this.props.navigation` is accessible

Comment: Ok - remove the arrow function inside the new Function :) @fiix

Comment: it show this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'. Expected a ':' following the property name 'this'.`

Comment: Change the new Function to this: ```let nyobaFunc = new Function(`return ${this.state.stringToFn}`)``` and remove the invoking of the new Function (the () at the end of the new Function).

Comment: throwing the same error immediately before i tap the button

Comment: I updated my answer  - if you write it like this the new Function will never be triggered before the tap.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to try after changing the code as follows?

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        stringToFn="navigate(\'otherscreen\')",
        stringToFn2="alert(\'otherscreen\')"
    };
...
render() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
...
 let nyobaFunc = new Function('navigate',`return  + ${this.state.stringToFn}`)

   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => nyobaFunc(navigate)} style={styles.flatListButton}>
```

Comment: same error, and the function call immediately after render before i press the button

Comment: @flix  I added a Navigate as a parameter. Would you like to try my answer again?

Comment: i'm not try this code yet, because i've a question, why i need to create a param? does the code still work for `this.state.stringToFn2`

Comment: @flix Function is working, but 'this.props' is not readable, causing an error. That's why we're trying to eliminate this error by going beyond the parameters.

Comment: these code work, but still the function running immediately so i added `()=>` after `return` in `nyobaFunc`. +1. but i can't read these code properly #sweat

Comment: @flix I'm sorry. I forgot to bind. I modified the code. What do you mean you can't read?

Comment: @flix If your problem is solved, would you choose my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `navigation` prop is undefined. Add a null check before invoking.

```
this.props.navigation && this.props.navigation.navigate(\'otherscreen\')
```

Comment: Why aren't you creating a normal function instead of using `new Function`?

Comment: i want to create a dynamic function, so the function getting from API, i need to convert the string of function into the function itself

Answer (score 0):

From your comment `i want to create a dynamic function, so the function getting from API, i need to convert the string of function into the function itself` I think you want a solution where you are mapping a string to possible functions.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});

class App extends React.Component {
  handlePress = () => {
    const taskName = 'navigate'; // get the name of the task from api

    // taskName to task mapping
    switch (taskName) {
      case 'navigate':
        this.props.navigation.navigate('otherscreen');
        break;
      case 'alert':
        alert('otherscreen');
        break;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress}>
          <Text>Do API Task</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i think it's break the dynamically itself, because i need to defined all possible function before execute it,